Pine script - increasing array element value
Can anybody help me find error in script? I fill array with 0's and 1's and for index one before last if equal 1 I want to increase value by 1
//@version=5
var int [] arr = array.new_int()
var int curval = 1
if close > open
    array.push(arr,1)
    if array.size(arr) >= 2
        if array.get(arr, array.size(arr) - 2) > 0
            curval := array.get(arr, array.size(arr) - 2)
            array.set(arr, curval, curval + 1)
else
    array.push(arr,0)

